# Is it possibile to delete an account from a stack?

Tags: feature-request, deleted-users

This needs no explenation. I want to delete my account from a stack but I want to keep it on others.

Is this possibile?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: When you need to find a site feature, always check the help center first. Or you could, like, google the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

The help center has all the details:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleting-account